# Trying to check whether a radio button is checked or not

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check whether a radio button is checked or not on the website http://www.makemytrip.com/, but it always shows false.

```
public static void cBoxRbtnDd () throws Exception{
    driverGlobal.get("http://www.makemytrip.com/");
    driverGlobal.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    String rdBtn = ".//*[@id='one_way_button1']/span";
    boolean att = driverGlobal.findElement(By.xpath(rdBtn)).isSelected();
    System.out.println(att);

    driverGlobal.findElement(By.xpath(rdBtn)).click();

    WebElement radioBtn = driverGlobal.findElement(By.xpath(rdBtn));
    new WebDriverWait(driverGlobal,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(radioBtn));

    boolean att1 = driverGlobal.findElement(By.xpath(rdBtn)).isSelected();
    System.out.println(att1);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons are normally created using the `<input>` with the attribute `type="radio"`. If you notice the radio button's on the site, they are actually using `<a>` tags and DOM manipulation to create the radio buttons.

The effect of the radio button been selected is done by CSS. Notice, that the selected radio button has a class `active`. Hence, you need to check if the class contains the value `active` to know if it has been selected.

You can use the code snippet given below:

```
public boolean ifActive(WebElement element) {
    String classes = element.getAttribute("class");
    return classes.contains("active");
}
ifActive(driverGlobal.findElement(By.id("one_way_button1")));    //false
ifActive(driverGlobal.findElement(By.id("round_trip_button1"))); //true
ifActive(driverGlobal.findElement(By.id("multi_city_button")));  //false
```

The values in the comments are values which the function will return. Note that makemyrtip.com selects the round trip radio button by default initially.

Comment: Dear Jason Estibeiro
Thanks for your answer. I will try and let's you know. Once again thanks for your time.

Comment: @Selenium-Help - Awesome! Do give it a green tick.